# How does "next" work in react-redux middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux. I have a simple app where you can add input text to an unordered list. I have middleware that prevents specific words from being displayed. I don't understand the order of operations that implement middleware. From what I understand, when I trigger a dispatch, what happens is something along the lines of:

1. Trigger dispatch from form submit event

```
// title is an object with a string
function handleSubmit(event) {
    props.addArticle(title);
}
```

2. Go through middleware function:

```
// store.js
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, // this is defined elsewhere and effectively handles actions
  applyMiddleware(forbiddenWordsMiddleware)
);
```

```
// middleware.js
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/constants.js";
const forbiddenWords = ["spam", "money"];
export function forbiddenWordsMiddleware({ dispatch }) {
    return function (next) {
        return function (action) {
            if (action.type === ADD_ARTICLE) {
                const foundWord = forbiddenWords.filter((word) =>
                    action.payload.title.includes(word)
                );
                if (foundWord.length) {
                    return dispatch({ type: "FOUND_BAD_WORD" });
                }
            }
            return next(action);
        };
    };
}
```

How does the above function actually work with createStore and applyMiddleware? Especially confusing to me is the `next(action)` line. Where do next and action come from? I'm having trouble visualizing the linear execution from form submit to checking for forbidden words.

Answer (score 9):

Middleware form a pipeline around the actual Redux `store.dispatch` function.  When you call `store.dispatch(action)`, you're actually calling the first middleware in the chain.  Inside of the middleware, [`next` passes a value to the next middleware, while `storeAPI.dispatch` restarts the pipeline](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#is-it-ok-to-have-more-than-one-middleware-chain-in-my-store-enhancer-what-is-the-difference-between-next-and-dispatch-in-a-middleware-function).  `action` is the value that was passed in to `dispatch` (or passed to `next` from the previous middleware).

This visualization may help:

[image: Redux middleware pipeline diagram]

The actual implementation is admittedly [a bit of magical code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/v4.0.5/src/applyMiddleware.js#L19-L41), but not something you should need to worry about.

For more details, see [the "Extensibility and middleware" section of my "Redux Fundamentals Workshop" slides](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/06/redux-fundamentals-workshop-slides/), as well as [these articles on how Redux middleware work](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-middleware.md).

Comment: Two questions: is "next" simply a pointer to the next middleware function? How does execution continue after going back to the first middleware?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `next` _is_ the next middleware function in the pipeline (or, if this is the last middleware, `next` is the real `store.dispatch` method itself).  If you call `dispatch()`, the entire pipeline sequence restarts per the diagram.

Comment: In the diagram, what is middleware 3?

Comment: Any middleware you want. The point is to illustrate the data flow, not worry about the details of how a specific middleware is implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @markerikson. I understand that `storeAPI.dispatch` restarts the pipeline, but I'm not sure how to use it without causing an infinite loop. Would it please be possible to take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66467615/10841085) at your convenience?

Answer (score 8):

In this context, `next` simply means that this middleware is not interested in that particular action, and wants to pass it to the other middlewares to take care of it.

When you give your middleware to the applyMiddleware function, it first calls each middleware and passes it something called `middlewareAPI` [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.ts#L74). Then starts with the last middleware, and calls it and gives the `store.dispatch` to it then sends the result of it to the middleware, which comes before the last one. And continues like this (passing the result of the latter middleware to the middleware that comes before it) all the way to the first middleware.

So let's say you have these three middlewares: `[a, b, c]` and you pass all of them to the applyMiddleware function. here is what happens:

1. First, every middleware gets called with the `middlewareAPI` object, which basically is an object containing the original `store.dispatch` and `store.getState`.

   ```js
   const middlewareAPI = { getState: store.getState, dispatch: store.dispatch }
   const aInChain = a(middlewareAPI);
   const bInChain = b(middlewareAPI);
   const cInChain = c(middlewareAPI);
   ```
2. Second, we call every middleware with the result of the previous call of the middleware that comes after it. Expect for the last middleware that doesn't have anything after it and gets the original dispatch as input.

   ```js
   const finalC = cInChain(store.dispatch);
   const finalB = bInChain(finalC);
   const finalA = aInChain(finalB);
   ```
3. We then set the final version of the first middleware, as the dispatch of the new enhanced store. So for example, when you call `store.dispatch({ type: "Hello" })`, the `finalA` function gets called, and if it calls the `finalB` function that is provided to it as `next`, then the next middleware in the chain gets called with whatever action the `finalA` gives to it. And it goes like this for the whole chain.

So in the example that we have in the question, there are two return statements in the middleware. The first one is the `return dispatch({...})` and the second one is `return next({...})`.

In both of them, our middleware says that it has finished its job with this action and lets the dispatch chain continue; But in the first return statement, the middleware calls the original `dispatch` directly and passes a new action with a new type to the `dispatch`. So the action that has been passed to our middleware initially, will get completely forgotten. This statement breaks the chain of the middlewares, before the action reaches the store, and starts a new dispatch with a new action.

In the second return, our middleware calls the `next` function, which as I described before, is the next middleware in the row, and our middleware sends the original `action` to it without changing anything. So the result would be like when this middleware didn't exist at all.

In this scenario, our middleware merely says "I don't care about what this action is; I want to send it through to the next middlewares to decide about whether it should reach the `store.dispatch` or not".

Comment: Your last paragraph has a lot of "it" and general statements like "the middleware". Could you edit your post and add some more specificity? Ex: "In both of them, the middleware says". Which middleware?

Comment: When/how will the original dispatch action reach the store? I think something represented linearly would be helpful, similar to above.