# Redux - Calling storeAPI.disapatch(action) inside middleware causes 'too much recursion'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working through the Redux fundamentals tutorial. In the section on ['Writing Custom Middleware'](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#writing-custom-middleware), we learn that middleware are written as a series of three nested functions like so:

```
// Outer function:
function exampleMiddleware(storeAPI) {
  return function wrapDispatch(next) {
    return function handleAction(action) {
      // Do anything here: pass the action onwards with next(action),
      // or restart the pipeline with storeAPI.dispatch(action)
      // Can also use storeAPI.getState() here

      return next(action)
    }
  }
}
```

`exampleMiddleware` is explained as follows:

> **exampleMiddleware**: The outer function is actually the "middleware"
> itself. It will be called by applyMiddleware, and **receives a storeAPI
> object containing the store's {dispatch, getState} functions**. These
> are the same dispatch and getState functions that are actually part of
> the store. **If you call this dispatch function, it will send the action
> to the start of the middleware pipeline.** This is only called once.

I didn't understand what was meant by the second last sentence (`If you call this dispatch function, it will send the action to the start of the middleware pipeline`), so I tried calling `store.dispatch(action)` inside one of the middlewares provided in `src/exampleAddons/middleware.js` of the example app to see what happens and got "too much recursion". [**Here's the demo.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-middleware-y29h9)

So `storeAPI.dispatch()` is the *composed* dispatch function of all the middlewares combined rather than the original store's `dispatch`, which would explain the recursion. **But then what is the use of `storeAPI.dispatch()`? Am I using it incorrectly?**

In `applyMiddleware`'s [source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/v4.0.5/src/applyMiddleware.js#L19):

```
function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {
  return createStore => (...args) => {
    // ...1) createStore is called and the resulting store is saved as `store`
    const store = createStore(...args)
    
    // ...2) a `dispatch` variable is defined and assigned some function
    let dispatch = () => {
      throw new Error(
        'Dispatching while constructing your middleware is not allowed. ' +
          'Other middleware would not be applied to this dispatch.'
      )
    }
    
    // ...3) a middlewareAPI object is defined containing the store's getState method and the `dispatch` function from 2).
    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args)
    }
    
    // ...4) the middlewares passed to applyMiddleware are called with the `middlewareAPI` object from 3) and the resulting functions are saved in array `chain`.
    const chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
    
    // ...5) the middlewares are composed and the resulting "composed" middleware function is called with `store.dispatch`. 
    // This returns a composed dispatch function that chains together the `handleAction` functions of all the middlewares passed to applyMiddleware. 
    // This composed dispatch gets assigned to the `dispatch` variable from 2). 
    // Since the `storeAPI.dispatch` is referencing this variable, calling `storeAPI.dispatch` now calls the composed middleware function, which causes the infinite loop. 
    dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)

    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch
    }
  }
}
```

The infinite loop seems to be the result of the re-assignment at step 5 in the annotations above. But I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct or if I'm even using `storeAPI.dispatch` correctly. I would appreciate any guidance the community could provide here as I wasn't able to find any examples of middleware that call `storeAPI.dispatch()`.

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1446) sheds some light on usage. `storeAPI.dispatch` seems to be useful for conditionally dispatching an action in a middleware, e.g. `if (condition) { storeAPI.dispatch(someOtherAction) } else { next(action) }` - if the condition is true, then someOtherAction will be passed through the middleware pipeline, otherwise the current action will be passed on to the next middleware. You can see this pattern in use [here](https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise/blob/master/src/index.js#L14).

Comment: It would help to have an example of this in the docs. I understood that `storeAPI.dispatch` 'restarts' the middleware chain but wasn't sure why that was a useful feature to have until I saw the links in my previous comment.

Comment: [storeAPI.dispatch(action)](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-middleware-y29h9?file=/src/exampleAddons/middleware.js:103-131) will dispatch the action again so redux will run the middlewares that will call `storeAPI.dispatch(action)` again so redux will run the middlewares that will call `storeAPI.dispatch(action)` again, there is your infinite loop. It's like writing a recursive function that never stops recurring: `const recur = (arg)=>recur(arg)`

Comment: If you look at a thunk implementation you will see that it won't call next if the action is a function: `const thunkMiddleware = ({getState,dispatch}) => next => action => typeof action === 'function' ? action(dispatch,getState) : next(action)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, calling `storeAPI.dispatch()` in a middleware sends the action to the very start of the middleware pipeline.  That means that if we have middlewares `a->b->c->store`, and `b` calls `storeAPI.dispatch({type: "some/action"})`, middleware `b` will see that exact same action object go through almost immediately.

Because of that, **a middleware should never call `storeAPI.dispatch()` unconditionally, because that *will* cause infinite loops!**  This is basically the same problem as something like calling `setState()` unconditionally in a React component `useEffect` hook.  The effect runs after rendering, and `setState()` queues up another render, so if you always set state every time, you always force a re-render, and that's an infinite loop.  Same thing here.

So, any use of `storeAPI.dispatch()` in a middleware should be wrapped in a conditional check so that it only happens *some* of the time, not *all* of the time.

Comment: Thank you @markerikson, it didn't occur to me that it should be used conditionally. That's exactly how it is used [here](https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise/blob/master/src/index.js).

Answer (score 0):

> But then what is the use of storeAPI.dispatch()?

Let's examine the naive implementation of thunk middleware. The middleware basically allows `dispatch` to receive a function (called **dispatch function**) as its argument (which is normally a plain action object).

```
const asyncFunctionMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
        return action(store.dispatch, store.getState); // (*)
    }
    return next(action);
}
```

Async logic will go inside the **dispatch function** which has been provided with two essential arguments: `dispatch` and `getState` - See line (*).

These two arguments are sufficient for developers to interact with the redux store in their async logic. And for the intended use-case, developer's will is to be able to dispatch an action as a normal operation (with all the provided middleware feature). Therefore, a `store.dispatch` is used here in the implementation.

**What happen if we passed `next` instead?**
Depend on the position of the thunk middleware in the middleware list, the `next` will be the next wrapped dispatch object followed by thunk middleware.
Imagine the order is `a->thunk->b->store`. Then dispatch using next in thunk will give your no effect of middleware `a` on the action.
This behavior isn't desired in the thunk use-case, hence using `store.dispatch` here is appropriate.

Therefore, thunk is a situation that we should make use of `store.dispatch` in middleware